# csh grep not displaying newline between results

Tags: grep, csh

I need to find all lines matching my search string in a file.
This is a simple test version of the script, but grep is not displaying the results seperated by a new line:

```
# findtext program
echo Written by: 
echo Program Name: $0

set n = $#argv
set line_num = `grep -n "monkey" test5.txt`
echo $line_num
```

i tried:

```
echo "${line_num}"
```

can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: line_num=`grep -n "monkey" test5.txt` remove set and try with this it gives the right output!

Comment: if i do that it says : line_num: command not found

Comment: line_num: undefined variable

Comment: after line_num put = without spacing

Comment: still saying same thing.... i tried it with and without the ` `

Comment: i figured it out , apparently echo is no ones friend, this works..

Comment: # findtext program
echo Written by: 
echo Program Name: $0
set n = $#argv
set line_num = `grep -n $argv[1] $argv[2] `
echo $argv[2]
printf '%s\n' $line_num